# HSQLDB database webserver access

Tags: syntax

I need a database that runs its connection over http and not tcpip. The "HSQLDB (webserver)" jdbc driver should be able to do just that. The following code launces the webserver but the OpenSQLConnect is not a success. It delivers a java.net.socketexception unexpected end of file from server.

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
dbLocation = "e:\\folder\\webtest\\";
dbName2 = "testDB";
dbServer = 
 SQLServerLaunch[{dbName -> dbLocation} ]
dbConnectionObject = 
  JDBC["HSQL(Webserver)", "localhost/" <> dbName];
dbwebConnection = 
 OpenSQLConnection[dbConnectionObject, "Name" -> dbName, 
  "Username" -> "sa"]
```

So for some reason i don't have the above code right. Can you help? Running a normal HSQLDB server works fine with the code below:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
dbLocation = "e:\\folder\\hsqlTest2\\";
dbName = "testDB";
dbServer = SQLServerLaunch[{dbName -> dbLocation}]
dbConnectionObject = JDBC["HSQL(Server)", "localhost/" <> dbName];
dbConnection = 
 OpenSQLConnection[dbConnectionObject, "Name" -> dbName, 
  "Username" -> "sa"]
```

MMA 10.0.2 on win7-64

Comment: You can use URLFetch to connect to MongoDB using HTTP calls.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I researched MongoDB with RESTHeart API and Espressologic which connects a RESTFull API to MS SQL Server. Very interesting and for as far as I know the only way to access from within the Wolfram Cloud. JDBC cannot be used in the cloud to access external databases.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"] ;
dbLocation = "c:\\folder\\webtest\\";
dbName = "testDB"; dbServer = SQLServerLaunch[{dbName -> dbLocation}] ;
dbConnectionObject = 
  JDBC["org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver", 
   "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/" <> dbName];
dbwebConnection = 
 OpenSQLConnection[dbConnectionObject, "Name" -> dbName, 
  "Username" -> "sa"]
```

Comment: Rolf, thanks that worked in the desktop.